# How to translate this SQL Query into a NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, sql, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

how can I translate this SQL Query into an NSFetchRequest:

```
select max(ZSENTAT), * from ZMESSAGE where ZISINCOMING == 1 group by ZROOTMESSAGEID;
```

This is how far I got:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isIncoming == %@ AND sentAt == @max.sentAt", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
NSFetchRequest *request = _fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest;
request.predicate = predicate;
request.propertiesToGroupBy = @[ @"rootMessageId" ];
```

This results in an exception: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions

Thanks
Chris

Comment: Predicates are not equivalent to SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error arises because you need to restrict the fetch to only those properties in the "group by" and any aggregate functions.  In your case you need to limit it to `rootMessageId` and `max(sentAt)`.  To do this you have to specify the `NSFetchRequest`'s `propertiesToFetch`.  **Note, if you do that, then you must specify its `resultType` as `NSDictionaryResultType` and that will restrict you from using the change tracking (ie delegate methods) of `NSFetchedResultsController`**.

If you do want to achieve your fetch: specifying the rootMessageId is easy, specifying the max(sentAt) takes a little more work.  You have to create an `NSExpression` and `NSExpressionDescription`.  Take a look at the Apple docs for these, but the following should get you started:

```
NSExpression *maxExpression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"max:(sentAt)"];
NSExpressionDescription *maxDesc = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
maxDesc.name = @"maxSentAt";
maxDesc.expression = maxExpression;
maxDesc.expressionResultType = NSDateAttributeType; // I assume sentAt is a NSDate
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"rootMessageId", maxDesc];
request.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"rootMessageId"];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isIncoming == %@",[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
request.predicate = predicate;
NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
etc
```

The results array will contain dictionaries with two keys: "rootMessageId" and "maxSentAt".

Comment: thx for your great explanation. 2 more things: How can I still get all the fields of the selected entities? Can you give me some directions on how to effectively replace NSFetchedResultsController and still keep track of changes? KVO/eventing?

Comment: If you want extra fields, I would abandon the `propertiesToGroupBy` (perhaps you already had!).  Could you amend your model, to include a "most recent" attribute (which you would then have to manage)?  Alternatively, could you specify `rootMessageId` as the `sectionKeyName` for your fetched results controller, with your fetch sorted by `rootMessageId` and `sentAt`, and then only use the first item in each section?